# Datetimepicker rails parsing date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetimepicker

I have an event model with start and end time, and i want to set it with DateTimepicker. As i understand he write string value in form and then i need to parse it for Datetime.
Code was:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :end_time %><br>
    <%= f.datetime_select :end_time %>
  </div>
```

I change it for datetimepicker:

```
<div class="form-group">
      <%= label_tag :start_time, 'Start time' %>
      <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker">
        <%= text_field :start_time, nil, class: 'form-control'%>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And after that i need to parse the string value of date and time into DateTime, but don't know how to do it. Can some one help?

Comment: paste params which you are getting

Comment: @user123 params[:start_time]

Comment: I am asking for params[:start_time] value

Comment: @user123 don't understand you.  Value of start_time is date and time

Comment: what you are getting after submitting form in params

Comment: error in parsing date and time

Comment: in logs you can see params after submitting request. Please paste those values

Comment: @user123 starttime parameter missed, something wrong with datepicker or what?

Answer (score 2):

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= label_tag :start_time, 'Start time' %>
      <div class="input-group date" class="datetimepicker">
        <%= f.text_field :start_time, nil, class: 'form-control'%>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
      </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
          format: "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm"    
        });
    });
</script>
```

Change this with your code and check.

in your controller you can access it as follows:

```
start_time = DateTime.parse(params[:start_date], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i")
```

Comment: thanks it worked but parsing swaps day and month idk why

Comment: paste your params[:start_date]

Comment: start_time"=>"05/29/2015 10:22 AM",

Comment: also got error if day > 12, cos of swapping with month

Comment: anyway invalid data error. Check params of end time ( it is without datetimepicker)
"end_time(1i)"=>"2015",
 "end_time(2i)"=>"5",
 "end_time(3i)"=>"30",
 "end_time(4i)"=>"07",
 "end_time(5i)"=>"30",
 "repeat"=>"once"},
 "start_time"=>"05/29/2015 10:30 AM",

Comment: problem in datetimepicker.your js code $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
          format: 'yyyy-mm-dd H:i'    
        });
doesnt work. format doesnt change. im using bootstrap3-datetimepicker

Comment: sorry, if i add the format line to datetimepicker script it doesnt work.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, I hope this will help.

Try out in **Rails Console**

```
Time.strptime("05/29/2015 10:22 AM", "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M ℅p")

#Output "2015-05-29 10:22 AM"
```

Comment: @Damir Nurgaliev According to your params I hope this will help you